# How to change column name on Custom List in SharePoint without having to change at the new item page

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, custom-lists

As said in the title above, i wanted to change the column name using some script or easier way out possible, on my custom list and not on the new item custom list page. 
I hope there's a way out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy.

1. Open the list view.
2. Navigate as shown in the below image.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oTdU.png)

This won't change the internal column name. Hence it will remain the same in the new form.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you get into this page/design?

Comment: This is the modern view of SharePoint pages. List Settings-->Advanced Settings--> navigate to the last part of the page, you can see "new experience" radio button. Check that.  Or you can simply find "Exit classic experience" at the left bottom corner of your list view page(right below the navigation section).

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. Im still unable to get the page/design though. 
I think is my work environment disable the function. 
Hope to see more alternative to my issue

Comment: Sorry I couldn't answer. Please add a screenshot of your list view and/or list settings page. This might help to get a better response. Btw if you change the column name anywhere it won't change the internal name of that column.